# Session crash for an unknown reason when using pickle.dump in Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I am working on Google Colab environment to create a Siamese network using Keras. I have used this code from [GitHub](https://github.com/akshaysharma096/Siamese-Networks). But I get an error when I tried to run the `pickle.dump` code:

```
with open(os.path.join(save_path,"train.pickle"), "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump((X,c), f)
```

The error : `OverflowError: cannot serialize a bytes object larger than 4 GiB`

So, I used Use pickle with protocol=4

```
pickle.dump((X,c), f, protocol=4)
```

but the session stopped during running this code and I got this message `"Session crash for an unknown reason "` and `Your session crashed after using all available RAM`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your runtime is crashing out of memory.

I was able to pickle 4 GB of data, but it required ~8G of memory in Python to do so.

You can view the runtime logs with 'View runtime logs' for the Runtime menu. That often has hints about crashes. In this case, it reports many large allocations.

Example:
[image]

The sessions manager will show memory. In my case, without doing anything else:

[image]

Comment: The Kernel restarted. I get this message also `Your session crashed after using all available RAM`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and its working for me

```
import pickle
pickle_out = open("train.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump((X,c), pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```